# How to prove it is a strictly stationary process?

Tags: probability, statistics, stochastic-processes, random-variables

$ξ(t) = z*sin(ωt + θ)$ where $z$ is a random variable and its distribution is unknown and $θ$ is another random variable that is independent of $z$ and $θ$ is uniformly distributed on $(0, 2\pi)$. Besides, $ω$ is a constant greater than $0$. I've been asked to show $ξ(t)$ is a strictly stationary stochastic process using characteristic function or say $E(e^{jvξ(t)})$.

I've tried but it seems that $E(e^{jvξ(t)})$ depends on the $t$ I choose, which means it is not a strictly stationary stochastic process. I think my answer can be wrong and how to prove it?

One more question: I've got quite confused why a characteristic function of a stochastic process can be used to prove property of strictly stationary?
The definition of strictly stationary is $F_ξ(x_1, x_2, x_3,..., x_n; t_1, t_2, t_3,...,t_n) = F_ξ(x_1, x_2, x_3,..., x_n; t_1 + τ, t_2 + τ, t_3 + τ,...,t_n + τ)$ where capital $F$ denotes the probability distribution function(PDF) of ξ(t). My book never told me anything about relationship between characteristic function of a stochastic process and its PDF. So when this problem appeared, I think they want me to show $E(e^{jvξ(t)})$ does not depend on $t$ while forget to tell me why not depending on $t$ imply its strictly stationary?

Comment: The process is stationary (wide sense and strictly I think), but calculating the characteristic function do not seem to be the simplest way to prove it.

Comment: @Enredanrestos: What is your idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT**

To compute the characteristic function we can use the so called tower rule:

$$E\left[e^{j\times v \times ξ(t)}\right]=E\left[E\left[e^{j\times v\times Z \times \sin(ωt + θ)} \mid Z\right]\right].$$

Since $Z$ and $\theta$ are independent we can tell that

$$E\left[e^{j\times v\times Z\times \sin(ωt + θ)}\mid Z=z\right]=E\left[e^{j\times v \times z\times  \sin(ωt + θ)}\right]=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}e^{j\times  v \times z\times \sin(ωt + x)}dx.$$

I cannot formally prove but I am convinced that

$$\int_0^{2\pi}e^{j\times  v\times  z \times \sin(ωt + x)}dx$$

will not depend on $t$.

This statement is intuitively clear if we take into account that the integral above has a real part and an imaginary part (For the sake of simplicity, let $v=z=\omega=1$):

$$\int_0^{2\pi}e^{j\times \sin(t + x)}dx=$$
$$=\int_0^{2\pi}\cos(\sin(t + x))dx+j \int_0^{2\pi}\sin(\sin(t + x))dx.$$

In the figure below I depicted the two integrands for $t=0$:

[image]

The blue curve is the integrand of the real part and the red curve is the integrand of the imaginary part. If we chose another $t$ then we would get the same curves shifted accordingly. The result of the integrals would be $0$ for the imaginary part and a fixed positive number for the real part independently of $t$. (This fact is independent of $\omega, v$, and $z.$)

Comment: Thanks. I didn't got answer notification until I got in just now. I have one more question do you know why does characteristic function not depending on t imply its strictly stationary?

Comment: @Bearandbunny: I know only that the time independence of the characteristic function implies the time independence of all the moments. To be honest, I don't know the formal proof that then the multidimensional distribution functions will be time independent. But I am still convinced...

Comment: It doesn't matter. I appreciate your note that " the time independence of the characteristic function implies the time independence of all the moments". Can you tell me how or where did you get this idea? I mean do you have some books recommended?

Comment: @Bearandbunny: I studied stochastic processes from this book: https://books.google.hu/books?id=NCTwCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA561&lpg=PA561&dq=Gihman+Skorokhod&source=bl&ots=2DNiXZ9MeK&sig=sJ1TYv-QlKYEE0wwPcUhaaBazWs&hl=en&sa=X&ei=se-FVbCeEML-UKD8gNAF&ved=0CCYQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=Gihman%20Skorokhod&f=false -- thousands of years ago.

Comment: I do not think this is correct. Specifically, you have in the end that $E[e^{jv\xi}]$ depends on $z$, which I think does not make sense.

Comment: @Enredanrestos:It is not $E[e^{...}]$ that depends of $z$. It is $E[e^{...}\mid Z=z]$ that depends on $z$. The characteristic function itself will not depend on $t$ if $E[e^{...}\mid Z=z]$ does not depend on $t$. So from the point of view of my answer the final integration was not necessary. Anyway: thanks fro paying attention.

Comment: I see. You are right then. By the way, to demonstrate that these integrals do not depend on t, you could derive on $t$ and use $\frac{d}{dt}\sin\cos(\omega t +x)=\omega \frac{d}{dx} \sin\cos(\omega t +x)$ and then do the integrals and see that you get cero.

Comment: $\frac{d}{dt}\int_b^af(x+t)dx=f(t+b)-f(t+a)$

Answer (score 5):

I am going to write a demonstration that the process is stationary, but I am aware this is not what the original poster asked since it is not based on calculating the characteristic function. This post is in response to a comment I made.

**Strict sense.** It suffices to show that
$$\mathbb{P}(z\sin(\omega t+\theta)\le\xi)$$ is independent of $t$.
But this is clear since  $s=\sin(\omega t+\theta)$ distributes in $(-1,1)$ with density $f_s=1/(\pi\sqrt{1-s^2})$ independent of $t$.

**Wide sense.** This becomes a bit unnecessary, but anyways. We need to show that the autocorrelation depends only on the temporal displacement, not the coordinate, that is, $\mathbb{E}[\xi(t)\xi(t+\tau)]$ is function of $\tau$ and not $t$. We have that
$$ 
\begin{multline}
\mathbb{E}[\xi(t)\xi(t+\tau)]=\cos(\omega t)\cos(\omega (t+\tau))\mathbb{E}[z^2\sin^2\theta]+\sin(\omega t)\sin(\omega (t+\tau))\mathbb{E}[z^2\cos^2\theta]+\\
\sin(\omega(2t+\tau))\mathbb{E}[z^2\sin\theta\cos\theta]~~.\\
\end{multline}$$

But $\mathbb{E}[z^2\sin^2\theta]=\mathbb{E}[z^2\cos^2\theta]=\mathbb{E}[z^2]/2=\mu_z^2/2$ (assuming it exists). We can separate the variables in the expectation since thet are independent.
Also $\mathbb{E}[z^2\sin\theta\cos\theta]=0$. We conclude
$$\mathbb{E}(\xi(t)\xi(t+\tau))=\frac{\mu_z^2}{2}\cos(\omega\tau)~~,$$
independent of t. Therefore the process is wide sense stationary.

Comment: I think you are correct. I got a deeper understanding of this question. I will up vote your answer with my appreciation.

Comment: you need to show the joint distribution is independent of time shift, that is $\mathbb{P}(X_{t_{1}+r}\leq x_{1}, X_{t_{2}+r}\leq x_{2}, \cdots X_{t_{n}+r}\leq x_{n})=\mathbb{P}(X_{t_{1}}\leq x_{1},X_{t_{2}}\leq x_{2},\cdots, X_{t_{n}}\leq x_{n})$ for all $r\in\mathbb{R}$, so why is it sufficient to only show $\mathbb{P}(z\sin(\omega t+\theta)\leq \xi)$ is independent of $t$?

Answer (score 3):

I know this is a post from 4 years ago, and you got two answers. However, it seems that the accepted answer did not give you a complete proof, and I cannot agree with the second answer in terms of strict stationarity.

To prove the strict stationarity, you need to show $$\mathbb{P}(X_{t_{1}+h}\leq x_{1},\cdots, X_{t_{n}+h}\leq x_{n})=\mathbb{P}(X_{t_{1}}\leq x_{1},\cdots, X_{t_{n}}\leq x_{n})$$ so only arguing the first dimensional distribution (as suggested by the second answer) may not be sufficient. Since that answer did not give you why it is sufficient, I think we need to be cautious here.

Here is an alternative but still straightforward proof (and I don't think the char function can give you any result of the time shift of the f.d.d, it only gives you if the f.d.d. is consistent).

---

So you have $X_{t}:=A\cos(\eta t+\phi)$ where $A,\eta\geq 0$ and is independent of $\phi$ which is uniform on $[0,2\pi]$. Let $h\in \mathbb{R}$.

Firstly, if $X_{t}:=\cos(t+\phi)$, then the proof is straightforward 
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(X_{t_{1}+h}\leq x_{1},\cdots, X_{t_{n}+h}\leq x_{n})&=\mathbb{P}(\cos(t_{1}+h+\phi)\leq x_{1},\cdots, \cos(t_{n}+h+\phi)\leq x_{n})\\
&=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\dfrac{1}{2\pi}\mathbb{1}_{\cos(t_{1}+h+y)\leq x_{1}}\cdots\mathbb{1}_{\cos(t_{n}+h+y)\leq x_{n}}dy\\
&=\int_{h}^{2\pi+h}\dfrac{1}{2\pi}\mathbb{1}_{\cos(t_{1}+\tilde{y})\leq x_{1}}\cdots\mathbb{1}_{\cos(t_{n}+\tilde{y})\leq x_{n}}d\tilde{y}\\
&=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\dfrac{1}{2\pi}\mathbb{1}_{\cos(t_{1}+\tilde{y})\leq x_{1}}\cdots\mathbb{1}_{\cos(t_{n}+\tilde{y})\leq x_{n}}d\tilde{y}\\
&=\mathbb{P}(X_{t_{1}}\leq x_{1},\cdots, X_{t_{n}}\leq x_{n}),
\end{align*}
where the third equality was obtained by a change of variable $\tilde{y}:=y+h$, and the fourth equality is obtained by the observation that the integrand is a $2\pi-$periodic function (since $\cos$ is ) and as such it has the same value of the integral over any interval of length $2\pi.$

Now, with $A\geq 0$ and $\eta\geq 0$,  we use the same spirit, but apply Fubini as follows:
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(X_{t_{1}+h}\leq x_{1}, \cdots, X_{t_{n}+h}\leq x_{n})&=\mathbb{P}\Big(A\cos(\eta(t_{1}+h)+\phi)\leq x_{1},\cdots, A\cos(\eta(t_{n}+h)+\phi)\leq x_{n}\Big)\\
&= \mathbb{E}_{A,\eta}\mathbb{E}_{\phi}\Big(\mathbb{1}_{A\cos(\eta(t_{1}+h)+\phi)\leq x_{1}}\cdots\mathbb{1}_{A\cos(\eta(t_{n}+h)+\phi)\leq x_{n}}\Big),
\end{align*}
then using the independence for the change of variable (so you can just treat $\eta$ as constant in the integral of uniform), and the hypothesis of $\eta\geq 0$ (so the integral length is still $2\pi$),  we go back to a similar case: 
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}_{\phi}\Big(\mathbb{1}_{A\cos(\eta(t_{1}+h)+\phi)\leq x_{1}}\cdots\mathbb{1}_{A\cos(\eta(t_{n}+h)+\phi)\leq x_{n}}\Big)&=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\dfrac{1}{2\pi}\mathbb{1}_{A\cos(\eta(t_{1}+h)+y)\leq x_{1}}\cdots\mathbb{1}_{A\cos(\eta(t_{1}+h)+y)\leq x_{n}}dy\\
&=\int_{\eta h}^{2\pi+\eta h}\dfrac{1}{2\pi}\mathbb{1}_{\cos(\eta t_{1}+\tilde{y})\leq x_{1}}\cdots\mathbb{1}_{\cos(\eta t_{n}+\tilde{y})\leq x_{n}}d\tilde{y}\\
&=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\dfrac{1}{2\pi}\mathbb{1}_{\cos(\eta t_{1}+\tilde{y})\leq x_{1}}\cdots\mathbb{1}_{\cos(\eta t_{n}+\tilde{y})\leq x_{n}}d\tilde{y}\\
&=\mathbb{E}_{\phi}\Big(\mathbb{1}_{A\cos(\eta t_{1}+\phi)\leq x_{1}}\cdots\mathbb{1}_{A\cos(\eta t_{n}+\phi)\leq x_{n}}\Big),
\end{align*}
where the second and the third equality were obtained due to the same reasons.

This implies that 
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(X_{t_{1}+h}\leq x_{1}, \cdots, X_{t_{n}+h}\leq x_{n})&=\mathbb{E}_{A,\eta}\mathbb{E}_{\phi}\Big(\mathbb{1}_{A\cos(\eta(t_{1}+h)+\phi)\leq x_{1}}\cdots\mathbb{1}_{A\cos(\eta(t_{n}+h)+\phi)\leq x_{n}}\Big)\\
&=\mathbb{E}_{A,\eta}\mathbb{E}_{\phi}\Big(\mathbb{1}_{A\cos(\eta t_{1}+\phi)\leq x_{1}}\cdots\mathbb{1}_{A\cos(\eta t_{n}+\phi)\leq x_{n}}\Big)\\
&=\mathbb{P}(X_{t_{1}}\leq x_{1},\cdots, X_{t_{n}}\leq x_{n}).
\end{align*}

Since this holds for all $h\in\mathbb{R}$, we are able to conclude that $X_{t}$ is strictly stationary.

---

This is basically an application of Fubini.

Comment: Could you explain $\phi(dy)$? or $\phi^{-1}(dy)$? i'm a little confused. thanks

Comment: @Bearandbunny sorry, I should use $dy$. Let me edit the answer.

Comment: @Bearandbunny basically the $\mathbb{E}_{\phi}$ is the expectation with respect to $\phi(dx)$, the uniform distribution. but the density is $\frac{1}{2\pi}$, so $\phi(dx)=\frac{1}{2\pi}dx.$

Comment: I guess maybe it is appropriate to write as $\phi^{-1}(dx)$ because $\phi$ is a measurable function from $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)  \to (\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$. I think this proof is very smart and will upvote it.

Comment: @Bearandbunny ah. You are right. thanks for your nice words :)